# How can I avoid Slick's model declaration verbosity and repetitiveness

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, slick

I am currently using Slick 1.x to access MySQL within playframework 2.1.3. While generally Slick's features look pretty good, I cannot wrap my head around how repetitive the declaration syntax is. I mean have a look at the following code:

```
case class User
 (id: Option[Long]
 , firstName: String
 , lastName: String
 , email: String
 , password: String
 , status: String
 , createDate: Long = Platform.currentTime
 , firstLogin: Option[Long]
 , lastLogin: Option[Long]
 , passwordChanged: Option[Long]
 , failedAttempts: Int = 0
  )

object User extends Table[User]("USER") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[String]("firstName", O.NotNull)
  def lastName = column[String]("lastName", O.NotNull)
  def email = column[String]("mail", O.NotNull)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  def status = column[String]("status", O.NotNull)
  def createDate = column[Long]("createDate", O.NotNull)
  def firstLogin = column[Long]("firstLogin", O.Nullable)
  def lastLogin = column[Long]("lastLogin", O.Nullable)
  def passwordChanged = column[Long]("passwordChanged", O.Nullable)
  def failedAttempts = column[Int]("failedAttempts", O.NotNull)

  def * = id.? ~ firstName ~ lastName ~ email ~ password ~ status ~ createDate ~ firstLogin.? ~ lastLogin.? ~ passwordChanged.? ~ failedAttempts <>(User.apply _, User.unapply _)
  def autoInc = * returning id
}
```

It can't be right, that in order to have a simple case class and an access object, I will have to declare each and every field three times. Is there a way to avoid this error prone repetitiveness?

**Update**: Of course a solution to this problem should support read **and write** operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code generation or in the future: type providers.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/Pdp3GTXsKCo/O0e3JLXAaK8J

Comment: From the thread: _"Source-code-generation-based type-providers will likely ship with upcoming Slick 2.1 later this year."_ i.e. they are not usable for production with 1.x.
Code generators are imo a really good way to produce more brittle code, but do not add much agility in exchange.

Comment: Basically it just solves the first step of the model management. You'll have to regenerate and lose changes etc. It's not a pattern I am comfortable with. But I guess until 2.x goes gold, this will have to do.

Comment: That is only true if you use "bad code-generators". With good code-generators you can work in a very agile way. The trick is that the code-generator either has to spit out code, which is extensible, e.g. base classes, which you customize in sub classes. Or the code-generator itself has to be fully customizable, which is the case for the generator at https://github.com/cvogt/migrations/blob/master/src/main/scala/SampleCodegen.scala / https://github.com/cvogt/migrations/tree/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc . Or both.

Comment: You can also integrate the Slick 2.0 code generator with Play Framework Evolutions, I posted a sample project here:  http://blog.papauschek.com/2013/12/slick-2-0-code-generator-play-framework-evolutions/

I think the question comes down to this: Code-First or Database-First? In essence, do you want to write SQL or Scala to define your tables? From my personal experience with larger projects I now prefer writing SQL to define my database. No more leaky abstractions.

Comment: Yes, look for code generation. We decided that precompilation code-generation was  more practical for now than macro-based code-generation.

Answer (score 5):

You could use direct embedding. It is an experimental, macro-based API that lets you write your tables like this:

```
@table("COFFEES") case class Coffee(
  @column("COF_NAME")  name:  String,
  @column("SUP_ID") supID: Int,
  @column("PRICE") price: Double
)
val coffees = Queryable[Coffee]
```

**edit**:

Docs are here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/direct-embedding.html

Comment: Oh - just noticed this from the docs **"The direct embedding currently does not feature insertion of data."** - that makes it unusable for me.